# Car Physics In the BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

I remember there was a tutorial on implementing the Car Physics wrapper in the BGE somewhere that I used before (the Python one with a rigid body car and collision-less wheels), but I can't seem to find that tutorial or something else that works in the latest version of Blender.  If there's anyone who can furnish a tutorial + code here, then I'd be much obliged.

Comment: You are asking for a tutorial, which is not the purpose of BSE, you should post your logic, script, the errors that may you get trying that configuration. And you will get a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought that was a valid thing to do here.